# Apply <script> tag to one only section of page

Tags: javascript, css

I am using a jQuery range slider [http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range][1]
which uses these two scripts:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

However, when I add those to my website, they conflicts with my `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

What is the easiest way to apply the `2` slider scripts only on one section of the website? It would look like (obviously next is wrong):

```
#range {
    url: <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: Did you try and not use `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>` since you are already calling jquery?

Comment: yes and the ranger slide did not work. I also tried putting the jquerys in different orders (but can try again)

Comment: Conflicting JQuery versions is something that can be somewhat resolved by JQuery noConflict - however, you should figure out if the prior version of JQuery is needed. If you're not supporting IE6-8, JQuery 1 is probably unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

**You can't target script references to portions of a page.**

The simplest thing is to use the much more current versions of JQuery and the JQuery UI.

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $("#slider").slider({
      values: [ 10, 25 ],
      change: function(){
        console.log($("#slider").slider( "option", "values" ));
      } 
    });

  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="slider"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You're correct, but with JQuery it's not "newer is better" as is often the implication. The use case between different versions of JQuery is often determined by the Browser Support they offer. I think this is important to point out.

Comment: @zfrisch I think we can all safely stop worrying about IE 8 or less.

Comment: haha, well... you would hope so - but unfortunately, at least in my niche of the woods, many of the corporations here have been slow to adopt browser updates. In fact my current position sees me having to write applications for IE8 compatibility often. Granted, it's the last holdout of the older Browsers and it'll probably be killed off when Microsoft makes the switch to Chromium, but it's still something to keep in mind as I doubt I'm the only one. I won't press the issue - it's ultimately your decision to include the information, and I've already commented. +1

Comment: Yep it works. However, something in my https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js is conflicting with datatables jquery plugin i believe which now makes this a much more complex problem. but thank you for your answer that is what i needed.